# preg_replace href or src only when protocol is missing

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've working on parsing an input, which is HTML. However, I need to be able to find all href or src attributes that DON'T have a protocol such as http://, https:// or ftp:// etc on them, and when they don't replace it with a variable that contains a protocol and domain.

So for example I want

```
<a href="/_mylink/goes/here">Link 1</a>
<a href="http://site.com/_myotherlink/goes/here">Link 2</a>
```

to return:

```
<a href="http://mydomain.com/_mylink/goes/here">Link 1</a>
<a href="http://site.com/_myotherlink/goes/here">Link 2</a>
```

I can get the whole href attribute, but I can't seem to work out how to only match and replace IF it's missing a protocol. I found that [^0-9] would work in a inverse/not way, but I found i couldn't get it to work when trying it with http:// etc.

Edit:

Just to make mention of it, as it's become obvious to me that it's part of the 'scope' of this question, I want to avoid having url encodings as a result of the replacement, as I use things like {} onto some of these, and I don't want them to have things like %7B %7D in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use the DOM to easily replace these attributes? For example

```
$domain = 'http://mydomain.com';
$currentPath = '/some/absolute/path/'; // make sure this starts and ends with a forward-slash

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$attrs = $xpath->query('//@href[not(contains(., "://"))]');
foreach ($attrs as $attr) {
    $attr->value = sprintf('%s%s%s',
        $domain,
        $attr->value[0] == '/' ? '' : $currentPath,
        htmlspecialchars($attr->value)
    );
}

$attrs = $xpath->query('//@src[not(contains(., "://"))]');
foreach ($attrs as $attr) {
    $attr->value = sprintf('%s%s%s',
        $domain,
        $attr->value[0] == '/' ? '' : $currentPath,
        htmlspecialchars($attr->value)
    );
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: I was writing a similar solution which used $doc->getElementsByTagName("a") instead, then used strpos() to filter out the the hrefs starting with "/". I like how your solution does both of these tasks together with the xpath. +1, nice.

Comment: This causes problems, as it seems to automatically urlencode() the attribute, which is a functionality I'm looking to avoid at that point of code. is there a way to turn that off?

Comment: @ScottFlack That's probably due to `saveHTML()`. Try `saveXML()` instead. Also, I've added `htmlspecialchars()` to the attribute value assignment as it appears you need to do this in PHP

Comment: @Phil Thanks, that seems to have made this solution work for my needs now. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

In essence you are looking for the "*not*"-pattern. That would be a [negative assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
 (?!http://)
```

Add that in `/href="(?!http://)[^"]+"/` for example.

Or you could use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) and sort it out there.

---

Since you said "parsing" it's kinda on-topic; the alternative would be [phpquery](/questions/tagged/phpquery) or [querypath](/questions/tagged/querypath) for HTML traversal. Then you can loop over all the links with:

```
 foreach (htmlqp($html)->find("a[href]") as $tag) {
      if (!strstr($tag->attr("href"), "http://")) {
             $tag->attr("href", "$add....");
```

Obviously overkill for output transformation. But might be a more resilient option for arbitrary HTML.

Comment: I really like how simple and short this looks, but I couldn't quite get it to work for some reason, though I think it's more to do with me than the actual answer, as I could get it to work in one of the online 'test regex' systems around, but not my actual site's code.

Comment: Extra thanks, as the (?!) has come in handy elsewhere in my code as well now, much appreciated!